# External volume limiter for headphones

Tags: headphones

Is there any device on the market that would allow to limit max volume of the headphones?

There are many external pass-through volume control devices, but they control overall volume. This device should only limit volume when it's over the certain level (for hearing protection). Ideally, the desired threshold would be controllable by the knob on the device.

ps. I'm aware of headphones with "hearing protection" function, but I need an external solution to apply for my existing headphones.

Comment: I got electronic music lessons, and we use compressors there, I think one of those could be what you are looking for if there is no budget limitation (those are very expensive)

Comment: ↑ The 'ultimate' compressor is a brick-wall limiter. You can get such things in software, even for free, but that would still leave a regular volume control later in the chain.